# Using functional calculus to show that $exp(S)exp(T)=exp(T)exp(S)$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $S$ and $T$ are two commuting normal operators in $B(H)$,how to use the continuous functional calculus to show that following conclusion?

$exp(S)exp(T)=exp(T)exp(S)=exp(S+T)$?

Can we derive the following formula:
$\exp (a) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} a^n,a\in B(H)$

Comment: The operators need to commute, otherwise it is not true.

Comment: If $ST=TS$,how to use the functional calculus to prove the equality?

Comment: If $ST=TS$ and $S,T$ are normal then the $C^*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$ generated by $S,T$ is commutative. Can you see how to continue?

Comment: @s.harp This is true, but non-trivial (Fuglede's theorem). In the case at hand it seems mich easier to simply commute the series expressions, which has the additonal advantage of being valid also for non-normal operators.

Comment: @MaoWao you are right (both about non-triviality that the algebra generated is non-commutative and that it is easier to take the exponential series). The OP was kind of focused on using functional calculus though. The answer by Martin Aregami gets around the non-trivial statement used and makes use of functional calculus, so I guess thats the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is to notice that $f(T)$ is in the C$^*$-algebra (von Neumann if $f$ is Borel) generated by $T$. Then $f(T)S=Sf(T)$. Now you repeat the argument, but with $f(T)$ and $S$ to get $f(T)g(S)=g(S)f(T)$.